# What's the difference between audioContext.destination and audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm wondering what the difference is between audioContext.destination and audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination().

Streams that generated from destination do behave a bit differently when they are played on browser pages. So I would like to know the best practice to use them separately and why.

Answer (score 1):

[`BaseAudioContext.destination`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/destination) (note it's actually from `BaseAudioContext` which `AudioContext` extends) is **not** a stream. It's a `AudioDestinationNode`. Per the doc, it usually represents a *real* output device:

> The destination property of the BaseAudioContext interface returns an AudioDestinationNode representing the final destination of all audio in the context. It often represents an actual audio-rendering device such as your device's speakers.

In the other hand, [`AudioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) actually *creates* an audio stream in which you can, for example, save to file or stream it futher through RTC. The result is a `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` which actually does **not** have any relationship with `AudioDestinationNode` except both of them have the same parent interface `AudioNode`.

> The createMediaStreamDestination() method of the AudioContext Interface is used to create a new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode object associated with a WebRTC MediaStream representing an audio stream, which may be stored in a local file or sent to another computer.

In short: `destination` represents an (usually) real output device, while `createMediaStreamDestination` creates an output stream that you can further process that stream/data/information.